# Count combined values from rows mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database that has a row called `clicks` and `user`. I want to count the value of all rows with `WHERE user='Oliver'`

I tried this:

```
SELECT count(clicks) FROM `stats` WHERE user="Oliver"
```

But that just count the amount of rows where the above statement is true. What I want is to count the values of all rows clicks `where user="Oliver"`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the SUM function.

```
SELECT SUM(clicks) FROM stats
WHERE user="Oliver"
GROUP BY user;
```

That will sum up all of the values in the `clicks` column for all rows where `user="Oliver"`.

Reference: [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: @Ben Is that not needed because I'm specifying a particular user?

Comment: It's not needed: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8123d/1 as you're only specifying a single user. If it were multiple and you wanted one row per user then you would need to group by.

Comment: @Ben Yes, I found this in the doc I linked to as well: "If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows."  Funny, I've always included GROUP BY out of habit when I use an aggregate function.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I don't know if MySQL is calling an internal "GROUPING" function within it's engine when an SUM is used.. didn't analyse that part off the source code.. take un look at this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/717493/11 but it is hard to say if the performance is better on the small dataset like this... one thing is sure parsing the SQL would take an little bit longer..

Answer (score 0):

Improved on [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19606756/2408342) by removing the `Group By`

```
SELECT SUM(clicks) FROM `stats` WHERE user = 'Oliver'
```